# Getting Application Context in Different Package

Tags: android, android-preferences, android-context, applicationcontext

I have to access the `Context` in different package. The thing which I am achieving is that I want to save a `Integer value` in `Preferences` and want to get the value in different package. Is there any way to achieve this? Actually, there is an asynchronous method which is being used in different package, and I want to do some processing before call come back to my package? How can I achieve this?

Comment: Show us your code please.

Comment: As long as it is inside the same application, the Context will be the same...

Comment: how to use it in other package as `getApplicationContext()` does not work in Different package

Answer (score 1):

**getApplicationContext()** will return you the context in application level. If you want to get the context is Activity level just use "**ActivityName.this**" or if its in fragment use **getActivity()**